# Why won't my select case find the value?

Tags: vba, excel, select, type-mismatch

I have a list of parts with dashes in them (ex. 1230-921) and I would like to find certain information pertaining to the part from the list to manipulate. Specifically I would like to copy and paste a value from the part to another worksheet. I have a drop down menu with the list of parts.
I have data on one sheet sorted by part number as mentioned before. On another sheet I would like to enter PN and veiw select stored info from the data sheet

```
Sub Recommend_2()

Dim somearray(28) As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim ALT As Variant
For i = 1 To 28
    ALT = Worksheets(3).Range("B15").Value
        Select Case ALT
            Case "1230-921"
                Worksheets(3).Range("C16").Copy
                Worksheets(3).Range("B5").PasteSpecial
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Error"
        End Select
Next i
```

End Sub

This has worked the best for me so far. The problem is that it cannot find the Case and it returns 28 errors. I have changed Dimension variables, range locations the whole nine yards. Any help is welcome even a new idea.

In summary)

1. I would like to find the part from the drop down menu
2. I would like to be able to manipulate a value from within the part on the list
3. I would like to do this for 28 parts

Comment: Have you hit a breakpoint on the assignment to ALT?  What is being put in there?  MessageBox it with your Error if you want to.

Comment: This code is **ONLY** looking at `Range("B15")`. Why are you doing this in a loop?  And what value is actually in `Range("B15")`?

Comment: It does not give me a breakpoint error. The program goes through straight to the case else error and gives me 28 of the msgbox.

Comment: I have a list of parts. Ultimately I would like to be able to put in different part numbers and it search for the part. I wanted to start simple with one part number so then I could make sure it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is going on without your actual spreadsheet, but I would suggest including the ALT in your error.

```
   ALT = Worksheets(3).Range("B15").Value
    Select Case ALT
        Case "1230-921"
            Worksheets(3).Range("C16").Copy
            Worksheets(3).Range("B5").PasteSpecial
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error: Value Found was:" & ALT
   End Select
```

Comment: Cool! I'm gonna try it out

Comment: Thank you. This got me to see that my worksheets were off. I used this and it came back correct. I then tried using ALT as a range between ("B14:B18") and it returns a mismatch error on "1230-921"

Comment: Your mismatch error is that a range of B14:B18 is not a string.  So you are comparing a range to a string and the computer goes "Huh?".  As if you are asking it to compare apples and oranges.

Comment: What you did worked for me to copy and paste my value as long as it is one cell. How can I find a certain cell within the range to do the action without directly specifying the cell?

ALT = Worsheets(3).Range("B14:B18").Value
instead of 
ALT = Worsheets(3).Range("B14").Value

I thought select case was the way to do this?

Comment: You can ForEach cell.  Loop from B14 to B18 checking each cells value.